# Join on two columns with missing records in second table

Tags: mysql, join

T1 is a Player table where the team is defined by the flag_district and spring_division. I need a count of players for all teams and need to match the coach in T2 to the team in T1. The two tables are related by the district and division fields. The below query works well **EXCEPT** if there is not a matching record in the coach table, in which case the result set does not return the team (flag_district and spring_division) or the count of players in T1. I need the result to show the player count of all teams even if there is not a coach record in T2. There may be a much better way to do this so all suggestions are welcome!

```
SELECT T1.flag_district, T1.spring_division, T2.lastname, count(T1.flag_district) AS players 
                    FROM jos_football_18_repeat T1 
                    LEFT JOIN jos_coaches_registration T2 ON T1.flag_district = T2.district 
                    WHERE T1.spring_division=LEFT(T2.division,1) 
                        AND T1.regtype IN (2,15) 
                        AND T1.regnum LIKE '3%' 
                        AND T2.approved = 1 
                        AND T2.current_year_approved = 'Y' 
                        AND T2.position='Head Coach' 
                        AND T2.Sport= 'Tackle' 
                        AND T2.season LIKE '%Spring%' 
                        AND T2.coach_year= YEAR(CURDATE()) 
                        OR T2.lastname IS NULL 
                    Group BY T1.flag_district, T1.spring_division, T2.lastname 
                    UNION SELECT T1.flag_district, T1.spring_division, T2.lastname, count(T1.flag_district) 
                    FROM jos_football_18_repeat T1 
                    RIGHT JOIN jos_coaches_registration T2 ON T1.flag_district = T2.district 
                    WHERE ( T1.spring_division=LEFT(T2.division,1) 
                        AND T1.regtype IN (2,15) 
                        AND T1.regnum LIKE '3%' 
                        AND T2.approved = 1 
                        AND T2.current_year_approved = 'Y' 
                        AND T2.position='Head Coach' 
                        AND T2.Sport= 'Tackle' 
                        AND T2.season LIKE '%Spring%' 
                        AND T2.coach_year= YEAR(CURDATE())) 
                        OR T2.lastname IS NULL 
                    Group BY T1.flag_district, T1.spring_division, T2.lastname
```

Comment: We need some sample data, current output and expected output. Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72340016/edit) with those information. By the way, a quick one.. your left and right join is currently acting like a normal (inner) join. This is caused by the condition you placed for the non-reference table columns in `WHERE`. Try changing the `WHERE` to `AND` as a continuation of `ON` join and see if there's any different in result.

Comment: What I mean is, from this `... ON T1.flag_district = T2.district WHERE T1.spring_division=LEFT(T2.division,1) AND T1.regtype IN (2,15) ....` to this `... ON T1.flag_district = T2.district AND T1.spring_division=LEFT(T2.division,1) AND T1.regtype IN (2,15) ....`. Similarly on the second `RIGHT JOIN` query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reworked this using sub-queries for the joins and was able to find a solution. Thank you @FanoFN for your help.

```
SELECT t1.flag_district, t1.spring_division, count(*) AS players, t2.lastname
                    FROM ( SELECT flag_district, spring_division, regtype , regnum from jos_football_18_repeat  WHERE regtype IN (2,15) AND 
                          regnum != '') AS t1
                    LEFT JOIN 
                    (SELECT district, division, lastname 
                    FROM jos_coaches_registration
                    WHERE approved = 1 
                        AND current_year_approved = 'Y' 
                        AND position='Head Coach' 
                        AND Sport= 'Tackle' 
                        AND season LIKE '%Spring%' 
                        AND coach_year= YEAR(CURDATE()))
                        AS t2 ON t1.flag_district= t2.district and t1.spring_division= LEFT(t2.division,1)
                  Group BY t1.flag_district, t1.spring_division, t2.lastname
```